# Changing CSS within jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntax-error

I am attempting to add a background image to a CSS class using jQuery, as shown below. Currently the code breaks all other jQuery, so I guess it must be a syntax issue.

I have added the two filters too for maximum support.

Any help would be really appreciated :)))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( ($(".coaching-section-1").length > 0) && ($(window).width() >= 481) && ($(window).width() < 1030) ) {
        $('.coaching-bg-private-video').css({
            'background', "url("wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg") no-repeat center right",
            'filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter', ""progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"",
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Because there are several syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is formatted incorrectly. You need to escape `"` that occur within other `"`. Also, the css method expects an object. Objects are formatted like this: `{key:value, key2:value2}`, not `{key,value, key2,value2}`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( ($(".coaching-section-1").length > 0) && ($(window).width() >= 481) && ($(window).width() < 1030) ) {
        $('.coaching-bg-private-video').css({
            'background': "url(\"wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg\") no-repeat center right",
            'filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their quick replies - this is entirely correct and has the most explanation - so it wins!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( ($(".coaching-section-1").length > 0) && ($(window).width() >= 481) && ($(window).width() < 1030) ) {
        $('.coaching-bg-private-video').css({
            'background', "url('wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg') no-repeat center right",
            'filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You include similar quotes in your `url` that is making the string break.  This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( ($(".coaching-section-1").length > 0) && ($(window).width() >= 481) && ($(window).width() < 1030) ) {
        $('.coaching-bg-private-video').css({
            background: 'url("wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg") no-repeat center right',
            filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/coaching-bg-private-first_frame.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')",
        });
    }
});
```